# NextJS 13 + TypeORM: Connection is not established with mysql database

Tags: mysql, next.js, typeorm

I am using TypeORM to query a MySQL database from a NextJS 13 api route, where I am running into spurious connection issues.

I've setup TypeORM like this:

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm'
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm'
export let AppDataSource: DataSource | null = null
export let UserRepository: Repository<UserEntity> | null = null

export async function setup() {
    AppDataSource = await new DataSource({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: process.env.DB_HOST!,
        port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT!),
        username: process.env.DB_USER!,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS!,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME!,
        entities: [UserEntity],
        synchronize: false,
        logging: false,
    }).initialize()

    UserRepository = AppDataSource!.getRepository(UserEntity)
}

@Entity({ name: 'USERS' })
export class UserEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'UID' })
    uid!: number

    @Column({ length: 255, name: 'USERNAME' })
    username!: string

    @Column({ length: 255, name: 'EMAIL' })
    email!: string

    @Column({ name: 'SIGNUP_TS' })
    signupTs!: number

    @Column({ name: 'LAST_LOGIN_TS' })
    lastLoginTs!: number
}

export async function getUserSQL(uid: number): Promise<UserEntity | null> {
    return UserRepository!.findOneBy({ uid })
}
```

From an API route I then call `setup()` followed by `getUserSQL()`. *Most of the time* it works perfectly fine, but I am spuriously getting `TypeORMError: Connection is not established with mysql database` on a subset of requests thrown from `getUserSQL()`.

I have already disabled HMR on the dev server with `NEXT_HOT_RELOAD=false next dev` but the issue still persists. From what I can tell, this does not seem to affect a production deployment.